# How can i insert a big table in IEEE template?

Tags: tables, ieee-style

I am using IEEE template for my paper writing. Now i want to insert a table which is 11x12. So it needs to stretch to the two columns format in the IEEE format. I did like this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{table}
 \caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|*{12}{p{1.11cm}|}}
\hline
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer & dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ \hline
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ \hline
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ \hline
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ \hline
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ \hline
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ \hline
dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ \hline
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ \hline
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ \hline
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ \hline
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and the output is:
[image]

The problem is that the caption is not centering between the two columns. How to do that??

How to center the table automatically between the two columns of IEEE format??

Comment: Try to use `\begin{table*}...\end{table*} -- this should span the full width of the paper, not just the first column

Comment: writing * giving me this error : ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

Comment: See the possible answer -- your table is too wide, in my point of view!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a `table*` environment instead of a `table` environment, to allow the tabular-like environment to span the width of both columns or, put differently, the full width of the text block.

In addition, you need to do something to assure that the overall width of the tabular-like environment indeed equals `\textwidth`. You may do this with either a `tabualarx` or a `tabular*` environment. For the table at hand, I would recommend you employ a `tabularx` environment, as it'll make it straightforward to equal widths to the data columns. I further suggest you define and employ a centered version of the `X` column type for columns 2 thru 11. Finally, I suggest you use the `l` column type for the first column and the `c` column type for the final column. (If you really want to left-align the contents of all cells, use the `X` column type for columns 2 thru 12.)

Oh, and do try to give your table a more "open" look by, say, getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines and by generating well-spaced horizontal rules with the help of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
% defined centered version of "X" column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} % for a bit more open "look"
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % filler text

\begin{table*}
\caption{CIFAR-10 Confusion Matrix}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{10}{C} c @{}}
\toprule
labels  
& airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer 
& dog & frog & horse & ship & truck & accuracy \\ 
\midrule
airplane   & 915      & 4          & 17   & 19  & 3    & 1   & 0    & 2     & 27   & 12    & 91.50\%  \\ 
automobile & 8        & 934        & 3    & 4   & 0    & 0   & 3    & 0     & 10   & 38    & 93.40\%  \\ 
bird       & 60       & 1          & 813  & 37  & 19   & 23  & 30   & 10    & 7    & 0     & 81.30\%  \\ 
cat        & 18       & 1          & 34   & 746 & 25   & 113 & 37   & 18    & 8    & 0     & 74.60\%  \\ 
deer       & 24       & 1          & 38   & 33  & 809  & 19  & 44   & 29    & 2    & 1     & 80.90\%  \\ 
\addlinespace
dog        & 4        & 0          & 37   & 106 & 23   & 792 & 9    & 26    & 2    & 1     & 79.20\%  \\ 
frog       & 2        & 5          & 19   & 35  & 1    & 20  & 912  & 2     & 3    & 1     & 91.20\%  \\ 
horse      & 14       & 0          & 26   & 20  & 18   & 28  & 4    & 886   & 3    & 1     & 88.60\%  \\ 
ship       & 35       & 10         & 3    & 2   & 0    & 2   & 1    & 0     & 936  & 11    & 93.60\%  \\ 
truck      & 23       & 37         & 4    & 10  & 1    & 2   & 2    & 0     & 15   & 906   & 90.60\%  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-15] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: why \end{table*} line giving me this error: ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

Comment: If i omit the * from the table then it prints but it overlaps with the other writings...

Comment: @setubasak - I don't get an error from the code shown above. If you get an error message about an "extra }", it is most lkely because you have an extra `}` hanging about somewhere.

Comment: @setubasak - Do you get an error message when you compile the code *as it is shown above*, or do you get an error message when you try to compile some other code?

Comment: I don't think so because when i omit i write \end{table} it then doesn't show the error but the table overlaps with the other contents

Comment: I am compiling my code with all other code and it shows the error at \end{table*} line.. But if i write \end{table} the error goes away then

Comment: @setubasak - *Of course* the table is going to be too wide if you try to place a `tabularx` environment of width `\textwidth` inside a `table` environment that has width `\columnwidth` (which is less than half the width of `\textwidth`). Please edit your posting and post the code that's giving you the error message about the "extra }`, so that it may be inspected.

Comment: removing \usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig} done the trick