# How can I add this long-table in Latex?

Tags: tables

[image]I have a long table and I want to add it inside paper IEEE access Latex format. The problem that the IEEE access Latex format has two columns. When I add the code I always get an error. Also, I tried to use the "long table" package, but It does not support two columns. In a word, I want to add a log table in the middle paper.
My table in latex

IEEE ACCESS Format

```
\begin{table*}[!h]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Long Table}
    \begin{center}

        \begin{tabular} {|p{60pt}|p{35pt}|p{38pt}|p{55pt}|p{100pt}|p{70pt}|p{80pt}|}    
            \hline
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name\\
            \hline
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name \\
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name \\
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name \\
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name \\
            Name& Name& Name& Name& Name&Name &Name \\                  
            \hline                  
        \end{tabular}               
    \end{center}    
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Longtable doesn't work in two column documents. You have two options: (i) manually split table into two part and insert similar as is sugested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/split-subfigures-over-multiple-pages/278748#278748 or (ii) instead `longtable` use `supertabular`.

Comment: @Zarko...Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Zarko, How can I add it in the center

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand you. `longtable` is automatically horisontal centered on page, however it doesn't work in two column document. Please extend your code fragment to small compilable document, which we can test and see, what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks for your answer. I add a simple latex code.

Comment: Please, consider my comment. We need complete small document with some dummy text (produced by `lipsum` package for example), beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Help us to help you!

Comment: In your question, you stated that you tried with the `longtable` package. The example code however does not use this package. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: @leandriis, Thanks for your answer. I add the default code that use in the IEEE access format, and that due to long table package not support the two-column page.

Comment: @Zarko, The problem I am not very experience to make your suggestion.

Comment: But you write your document! Make from it  a small test document which reproduce your problem. I cant write it for you, since I (and ithers here) don't know, what you doing. How an MWE (Minimal Working Example) looks like, see some answer on this site.

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks for your time and effort. I have already added a picture to the table as this table will be on multipage. I mean,  continue table.

Comment: @Zarko, The problem I want this table in the picture to extend on multi-pages.

Comment: This may help you-------https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305413/197451

Comment: @jsbibra, Thanks for your answer